# Python 3.2 Monte Carlo Pi Estimation?

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am just starting out with programming and this assignment is giving me a lot of trouble. How do I change the Monte Carlo code below (used for area under a curve) so that it estimates pi?

```
from random import uniform
from math import exp

def estimate_area(f, a, b, m, n=1000):
    hits = 0
    total = m * (b - a)
    for i in range(n):
        x = uniform(a, b)
        y = uniform(0, m)
        if y <= f(x):
            hits += 1
    frac = hits / n
    return frac * total

def f(x):
    return exp(-x**2)

def main():
    print(estimate_area(f, 0, 2, 1))

main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I won't solve this for you, but I will give you a hint. Think about embedding a [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) within a 2x2 square, and about how that might help you to estimate π. Once you figure that out, make use of the inherent symmetries to work with just one of the four quadrants.

Comment: Thanks. I am still completely lost though. This is the one assignment I havn't been able to complete, and mostly because I have no idea how to go about putting the shapes into the code. Can you give me a hint as to what part of the code for the area under the curve (above) I need to be changing?

Comment: @CalvinMerseal: You need to figure out two things: (1) what `f` should look like; (2) the appropriate values of `a`, `b` and `m`. I suggest that you draw a picture of what you're trying to do, and take it from there.

Comment: I clearly have no idea what I am doing. I am still wholly lost. Thank you for your help, but I don't think I am going to be able to figure this out.

Comment: I won't solve the problem for you either, but I will try to ask leading questions:  Do you know what the "def f(x)" statement is doing, on an intuitive level?  Can you sketch for yourself on a sheet of paper what it's doing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common example for Monte Carlo methods, see for example the Wikipedia page on [Monte Carlo Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).
Think about this problem in only one quadrant, so a quarter of a circle centered at 0,0 and the radius of 1 and a square from (0,0) to (1,1).
If you randomly put a point in the square at `x=uniform(0,1)` and `y=uniform(0,1)`, you can check if the point falls within the quarter circle, `(x^2.+y^2.)^0.5 <= 1.0`.
The chances this happens is related to the ratio of the volumes of the two objects.